# Bank statement requirements for UK standard visa

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I've read multiple answers regarding this question here on stack flow but still I want some clarification on my case.

I want to apply for UK standard visa next year to sit some tests.

One of the most important things as I understood was bank statement and other things that prove you have ties to your country that will force you to return to your country by the end of the visit.

My income is about $1650 monthly from 2 jobs and my wife's income is $800 monthly from 1 job in a public hospital.

I work in a public hospital as a doctor earning $750, and as part-time pharmaceutical salesperson in a private company earning $900.

I can provide a proof for my income from my job in the hospital with all legal certification and stamps from a governmental regulating body, but not from my second job since I can't authorize or certify the letter from my employer because it's not a properly regulated business in my country and there are no official documents regarding this, I can only provide a simple letter in English language from this employer explaining (my role, my salary, the period I've been employed) with their stamp only but no other official stamp from a governmental or a regulating body.

My bank account currently have a $700 after I have drawn about $6000 for house renewals.

I will restart depositing money again next month, and I want to reach like $12000 by next year to appear financially stable and capable. So what are my options?

Can I declare I have 2 jobs and I can deposit like $1250 monthly? Or keep my second private job a secret and that I only earn $750 monthly and deposit a monthly amounts of $500-$600 in proportion to this income?

Should I deposit and draw money regularly, or can I explain that I deposit about 75% of my monthly income because I keep %25 of it as it's enough for my monthly living specially that I live in family-owned house and I don't pay any rent?

Is it enough for me to have a bank statement so me and my wife can travel together to UK, or we should have separate accounts and both present a bank statement? Or we can have a joint account where we deposit like $1300 monthly together and both apply to visa using a bank statement for this joint account?

I'm short of time and need to do things properly and accurately starting next month so please help me.

Comment: Do you not have pay slips?

Answer (score 1):

I believe most companies in private sector can provide just a simple letter stating the needed information with a company header and a company stamp. This is what my husband and I attached to the application earlier this year and it was apparently enough. Also, we have a joint accout and it was fine too.